# Taking data from html form and inserting into mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, database

[image]

From a html form data is passed to a php code.It gives a error.

Comment: a. post code not an image. B. whats the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to design your site or write your code for you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard way to use.

```
$firstname=$_GET['firstname'];
$lastname=$_GET['lastname'];
$email=$_GET['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$email."')";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I use  '".$var."' .I think u are correct .'var' are also okay.clear your cache and run it.Your code is okay